# Return null of type ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a little question.. how can I return null of type Array List.. Here is the complete problem : RectangleList class manages a list of Rectangles. It has a constructor that takes an array list of Rectangles as a parameter. It has a method to return the Rectangle with the smallest area (or null if the list is empty).
Thank you!

Here is the code for what I have done :

```
public Rectangle smallestArea()
            {
            double min = list.get(0).getWidth() * list.get(0).getHeight();
            int k=0;

           if(list.size() > 0)
           {
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
                {

                if(list.get(i).getWidth() * list.get(i).getHeight() < min)
                {
                    min = list.get(i).getWidth() * list.get(i).getHeight();
                    k=i;}
                }

             return list.get(k);
           }

           else
               {
               return null;
               }
    }

    And I get this error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
        at RectangleList.smallestArea(RectangleList.java:39)
        at RectangleListTester.main(RectangleListTester.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.horstmann.codecheck.Main$2.run(Main.java:249)
    Error:

    Program exited before all expected values were printed.
```

I would also like to point out that this is not a homework for school.. it is something I simply work on and I got stuck here. Thank you for your support.

Comment: why not just return null?

Comment: can you add ore info?

Comment: Simply return `null`. There is no such a thing "`null` of type `ArrayList`".

Comment: return null; // it's as simple as that...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you show us a code sample?

Comment: -1 because it looks obvious that you haven't tried anything before posting the question.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`null` does not belong to any type and can be used of every type (excluding primitives).

So, you can always say `MyClass obj = null;`

Other problem can be if you have 2 overloaded methods with different parameter types, e.g.:

```
void foo(String s);
void foo(Integer i);
```

In this case attempt to call: `foo(null)` will produce compilation error because compiler cannot understand which one of 2 methods you mean. In this case you can perform casting:

- `foo((String)null)` will call first version of `foo()`
- `foo((Integer)null)` will call second version of `foo()`

Answer (score 0):

You can return null when you want. What you return is a reference to an object, and null is a universal reference to a non-existing object, so you don't have to cast it or anything.

```
public Rectangle getSmallestAreaRectangle() {
    if (theList.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    // ... do computations

    return theRectangle;
}
```

Comment: Doing someone's else homework is cheating ;)

Comment: Sometimes I cannot figure out if this is homework or just a new programmer lost in programming concepts :p

Comment: One point for you ;) But imagine if it was a pro at work : I would worry for his firm ^^